# Serving HTTP requests from the secondary AppDomain or avoiding application restarts when updating DLLs

Tags: asp.net, .net, marshalling, appdomain, provider

I`m searching for a solution that would let me update an asp.net website with new pages that are defined in various assemblies without the primary appdomain unloading (i.e. xcopy to /bin won't work).

While the cross appdomain invocation seems to be crystal clear for me, would it be possible to "provide" a System.Web.UI.Page living in another appdomain to the appdomain that is  serving ASP.NET requests?

Searching around build providers, virtual path providers and appdomains leaves me with a thought that the primary appdomain restart may be negligible compared to the effort and potential unstability of any secondary appdomain or custom build provider implementations.

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Why do you need to update the assemblie without restarting the application?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's *quite* as onerous as you suspect. I've worked with cross AppDomain invocation for an Outlook add-in to dynamically load different versions and there wasn't much to it. I've not done it in ASP.NET though, so don't know what traps you might fall into there.

Personally, I would explore two options:

1. Hit a break-point on a Page_Load event and examine the stack trace. See the call by System.Web.dll - IExecutionStep.Execute(), which steps into your web apps DLL? Something further down the stack has registered or otherwise determined which Page class is going to handle the request. The trick? subvert the standard behavior (sorry, not sure where or how, but I vaguely recall reading something about this once).
2. Subvert / bypass more of the web pipeline by implementing a module to explicitly handle your requests.

Edit: To elaborate on option 1, PageHandlerFactory class is the one I was thinking of. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pagehandlerfactory.aspx Of particular interest in the article is the comment "*To build a custom page handler factory, implement the IHttpHandlerFactory and register the custom PageHandlerFactory class in the Web.config file for the application in the httpHandlers Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema) configuration section.*"

In other words, if you implement your own PageHandlerFactory, you should be able to handle page requests however you want, including handing the requests to another AppDomain.